# Teardrop detected from TCP ACK from myself

Tags: linux, networking, router, firewall, tcp

I'm experimenting with linux (Debian 5.10) networking to allow me to connect two networks (eg. 192.168.0.0/24 with 172.17.0.0/16) together.

**Setup**

In my case it is a small server with one NIC, hosting VMs/dockers, that I want to connect to the physical LAN.

Both myself and the server are connected through a cheap ISP router/swtich combo.

To allow the routing, I configured that ISP router with the extra route.

**Tests**

From the server (VMs/docker that is also the router), to my computer I can send (and can see on the server) UDP and TCP traffic.

On the opposite site: UDP is working fine, but TCP... kinda. I can't fully open a connection.

However, if, instead of setting the route from the ISP router I put it on my computer, everything is working.

Another thing that work is, if use an IP in the same subnet as me, since the server is also the router, it has one. But this isn't what I'm looking for.

**teardrop attack!?**

TCP SYN, SYN ACK are working fine, I can see them going into the server and from my computer.

However, when my computer is sending the SYN (I'm assuming it is the SYN since the server never see a connection) the damn ISP router log a teardrop attack and drop the package.

From what I read about teardrop, it is when you try to create fragmentation packages with an invalid len/offset.

I open up wireshark to look at the SYN package:

- SYN set the "don't fragment" flag
- I can't see something odd with the segment offset (it is 0) or total len (40) - including on the PSH, ACK
- If I compare the package to a good connection, I can't see a difference
- From one example online, if there would be something wrong wireshark clearly set the detail line in red, plus, there is a remark in the info column about something wrong. I don't have anything like that.

I'm looking for any hint to allow the packages to go through without disabling the firewall or to set a better router.

Thanks

Comment: What's the route you've added? Is the routing symmetric in both directions? Some "attack" detection rules might not deal well with asymmetric routing (where packets one way go via the router but packet the other way don't, i.e. the router might be seeing an ACK without the previous SYN/ACK).

Comment: That one I'm not fully sure but:
From my client: ip is 192.168.0.101, gateway (ISP router) 192.168.0.1. ISP router is on 192.168.0.1 and handle 192.168.0.0/24 my itself I guess. But I also added a static route to 172.17.0.0/16 via 192.168.0.12. My server/docker server and router is: 192.168.0.12 and 172.17.0.1. No explicit route added by me but `ip route` use default 192.168.0.1; has 192.168.0.0/24 and 172.17.0.0/16 routes detected.